# Assistance with C++ simple_error()

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am independently learning C++ using the Second Edition of "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup. I have reached the end of chapter 3 and I am completing the drill. It involves writing a program that produces a "simple form letter, based on user input".

The task for step 5 of this drill is as follows (quoted word for word):

> Prompt the user to enter the age of the recipient and assign it to an **int** variable **age**. Have your program write "I hear you just had a birthday and you are **age** years old." If **age** is 0 or less or 110 or more, call **simple_error("you're kidding!")** using **simple_error()** from **std_lib_facilities.h**.

See my syntax below:

```
cout << "\n\nEnter the age of " << first_name << ":\n";
int age;
cin >> age;
cout << "   I heared you just had a birthday and you are " << age << " years old. \n\n";
if (age <= 0 || age >= 110)
    simple_error("you're kidding!");
```

Is my use of the 'if' statement, it's conditions and simple_error() correct as per the instructions of step 5?

It seems strange because the purpose of the program is to write a letter and `simple error("you're kidding!")` outputs "error: you're kidding!" in the letter... should I take this so literally?

I really appreciate your time and advice.

Comment: Does it work when you try it?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, the output is correct as far as the if statement goes. But is simple_error("you're kidding!") supposed to output "error: you're kidding!"? This is the first time simple_error() has been mentioned.

Comment: simple_error() is going print "error" before any error message you passed in as a parameter. Your code looks sound to me and your if statement is correct  so don't sweat the "error" part. You could replace simple_error() with cout<< if you wan't the "error" part gone.

Comment: I suspect that the intent is to write the "letter" only if there's no error. (That is, test the age first, and write the letter if I'm not kidding; the error message if I am.)

Comment: @RatHat thank you! I know it is such a trivial question but we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ahh, that makes more sense to be honest, but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program appears to follow the drill.

As far as the drill goes, it simply wants:

```
if (age <= 0 || age >= 110)
    simple_error("you're kidding!");
```

How the program behaves beyond that is out of scope for the drill, you shouldn't be concerned with how it formats the text. Just make sure it compiles, and what you wrote works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the definition of `simple_error()` from [std_lib_facilities.h](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h)

```
// error function to be used (only) until error() is introduced in Chapter 5:
inline void simple_error(string s)  // write ``error: s`` and exit program
{
    cerr << "error: " << s << '\n';
    keep_window_open();     // for some Windows environments
    exit(1);
}
```

The error is intended to go to `cerr` (standard error stream). By default anything to standard error is redirected to standard output.

If you don't want the error message in the letter, which I think you are concerned about, you can direct your standard error, for example, to a file on *nix systems like

```
./a.out 2>> error_file
```

Where, `2` stands for standard error stream.

As far as the drill goes your program is correct.